# Why is my conditional statement inside a switch being ignored?

Tags: android

What I want is to show a toast message that says "Fill in all fields!" when the user will not write something and then they click the SAVE button.

There is no error in the code but when I run it, it will completely ignore my else condition and will proceed in adding null items to my list.

I have read somewhere in to put a `break` but it still does not work.

Here is a snippet code of my MainActivity.java

```
    case R.id.btnsave:
        if(!studLname.equals("") || !studFname.equals("") || !cboCourse.getSelectedItem().equals(0)){

            String lname = studLname.getText().toString();
            String fname = studFname.getText().toString();
            String course = cboCourse.getSelectedItem().toString();

            student.setLname(lname);
            student.setFname(fname);
            student.setCourse(course);

            Student.studentArrayList.add(student); //Global arraylist

            Log.d("test", "students:" + Student.studentArrayList);

           listView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item successfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent home = new Intent(AddStudentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(home);
            studentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields can not be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
```

Comment: I think your If condition should have an && (AND) not an ||(OR)

Comment: you are comparing the edittext not the string, what you have to do is to get the string from these eidtexts

Comment: As some people mentioned below, `studLname` and `studFname` are UI controls, right? So you shouldn't be directly comparing them to the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two problems,

**One**: You must get the text from the edittext and then check wether it's empty

**Two**: You must use `&&` instead of `||`, Becuase if you use `||` when a single field is non-empty the condition is true. Therefore in order to make sure all three values are non-empty use the `&&` operator

Change your code as given below,

```
case R.id.btnsave:

String lname = studLname.getText().toString();
String fname = studFname.getText().toString();
String course = cboCourse.getSelectedItem().toString();

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(lname) 
    && !TextUtils.isEmpty(fname)
    && !TextUtils.isEmpty(course)){ 

    student.setLname(lname);
    student.setFname(fname);
    student.setCourse(course);

    Student.studentArrayList.add(student); //Global arraylist

    Log.d("test", "students:" + Student.studentArrayList);

    listView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item successfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent home = new Intent(AddStudentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(home);
    studentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    break;

} else {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields can not be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this conditional statement

```
if(!studLname.getText().toString().equals("") && !studFname.getText().toString().equals("") && !cboCourse.getSelectedItem().equals(0))
```

You need to get Text out of the Edittext before checking it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will remove the spaces also

```
    if(!studLnamegetText().toString().trim().equals("") || !studFnamegetText().toString().trim().equals("") || !cboCourse.getSelectedItem()getText().toString().trim().equals(0)){
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is incorrect. There should be `&&` instead of `||`.

```
if(!studLname.equals("") && !studFname.equals("") && !cboCourse.getSelectedItem().equals(0)){
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "&"(AND) instead of "||"(OR) in the if statement.
As of now, when either of the condition is true, that means only 1 field is filled and the other two are empty, then also it will enter the if condition and take null values for the NON-FILLED fields.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is a combination of everyone else's. 
Your "or" comparison will fire the inner check if a single box is filled in, except you aren't actually reading it correctly.  You need to add getText().toString() AND change || to &&.